# Eslint rule to ensure minimum variable name length, but not on JSON?

Tags: javascript, node.js, eslint

Our code has become a bit of a maintenance nightmare due to previous developers being liberal with single letter variables and little documentation. The latter we could deal with if the variables names were meaningful and self-descriptive. For this reason we are trying to set up eslint to avoid this going forward.

Our requirements:

1. minimum of two characters, since `id` would be an acceptable variable
2. allow `i` and `j`, since they are commonly used in 'for' loops as indexes
3. allow single letter properties on json, to allow `point = { x: 2, y: 2 }`

So far the best we have come up with is:

```
"id-length": [2, { "exceptions": ["i", "j"] }]
```

This covers points 1 and 2, but fails for point 3. Quoting single letter json attributes does not work for us to the `quote-props` rule being present and that we would rather keep.

Can anyone suggest an eslint configuration that would allow to support all three requirements?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[ESLint allows](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/id-length) the rule to not be applied on object properties with `"properties": never`. It's not enabled by default, so you have to specify it deliberately.

```json
"rules": {
  "id-length": [ 2, { "exceptions": ["i", "j"], "properties": "never" }]
}
```

Comment: I am not sure what the above syntax is but here is an example in `.eslintrc,json` file: `"id-length": ["error", { "min": 5, "exceptions": ["i", "j"], "properties": "never" }]`